# radio button in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i have nasted repeater which repeate a radio button for each questions i need make only 1 radio button in each queations  this is my code  , how i can make group for radio button control ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="text-left" >
            <strong>

                <div>
                    <strong>
                        <li>
                             <div id="outer" style="background-color: lightblue">  <%# Eval("QuetionText")%></div>
                           <br />

                        </li>
                        <div>

                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>

                                <div >
                                     <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  Text ='<%# Eval("ExamQuestionAnswerText")%>'  ></asp:RadioButton>
                                    <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("ExamQuestionAnswerText")%>' />--%>

                                </div>
                                    </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate >

                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                    </strong>
                </div>


            </strong>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: make only 1 radio button checkable in each question

Comment: If your repeater is bound to a collection of questions then you will only get 1 radio button per question.

Comment: per answer ( question have 4 answer ) i need user only use 1

Answer (score 0):

You can group your radio buttons in child repeater by binding its property GroupName like:

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  Text ='<%# Eval("ExamQuestionAnswerText")%>'  
GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId")%>'></asp:RadioButton>
```

You need to bring QuestionId for dataSource of child repeater.

Comment: that is not possible, you can only select one radio button out of same group. Can you inspect your html there must be some other issue. Try to produce your fiddle, and share with us

Comment: '<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  Text ='<%# Eval("ExamQuestionAnswerText")%>'  GroupName='<%# Eval("ExamQuestionAnswerId")%>' ></asp:RadioButton>'

Comment: Do not bind GroupName to ExamQuestionAnswerId, bind this to ExamQuestionId, it will works

Comment: Please create and share fiddle sample